# Addressing a person by their last name only

Tags: names, surnames, forms-of-address

I've seen a couple of instances where someone is addressed exclusively by their last name (not like "Mr. X" but only "X").

The most prominent example is perhaps MacGyver, whose first name (Angus) is never used to address him. It's *always* his last name, even for good friends.

So I'm wondering: Does this occur often in real life? What are the typical situations where someone would only use his last name?

Comment: It is sometimes done by a person in authority.

Comment: In fiction, _Morse_ demanded 'Morse' to avoid using his first name, 'Endeavour'. But this is really about arbitrary choices made by individuals or institutions rather than general rules of English usage.

Comment: Up to the 1950s, at least in Britain, men of equal status who were not close friends would normally refer to each other, and address each other, by a bare surname.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with arbitrary / subjective style preferences.

Comment: I was called 'Harvey' at my UK secondary school between 1963 and 1971.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey As indeed were we similarly called by our surnames, 1954-1961. Though some masters would invent nicknames for us (as we did for them) - something upon which modern teaching practice would frown heavily, I suspect. One chap called Thurlow, always got called Murgatroyd by the history master - I've never understood why.  Teachers were referred to as  "Mr..." by other teachers, except for the school caretaker, and the woodwork master (ungowned), who were referred to by surname only.

Comment: This varies by culture. Calling others by surname only in person used to be pretty common in a very wide variety of contexts, but has mostly fallen out of favor.

Answer (score 4):

In fee paying schools in the UK there is a tradition of boys being called by their surname, both by the teaching staff and also by each other.

There are a lot of people I went to school with, including friends, who I know by their surname, and also refer to me by my surname.

Comment: Not only fee-paying schools. Secondary Grammar schools, back in the day. Only exception at my school was the two Smiths in the class — R and RD.

Comment: The usage was not confined to schools. Even as late as the 1970s, it was considered quite normal in UK central government offices for male officials to address colleagues by surname, and to be so addressed by them. It did not signify one person being in authority over the other; it was regarded as a sign of being colleagues together.  There was an awkward phase later when the senior person one had been calling Mr Smith invited a more informal form of address, but leaving uncertain whther he meant "John" or "Smith".

Comment: @JeremyC It is even more complicated in France, where Christian names are not as much used as in Britain. Many people address their colleagues as M., Mme etc. But order is further disarranged by having the choice of *tu* or *vous*. And the use of such do not always correspond with Christian name v surname. So a range of intimacy levels becomes available.